# Context, name or explanation for a formula in the "law of rare events"

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function

The formula is

$$\psi(m) = \frac{m^m\,e^{-m}}{m!}$$

and it is described as *la probabilité de l'espérance mathématique dans la loi des événements rares* in the original paper by E.J. Gumbel's [*Les valeurs extrêmes des distributions statistiques*](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AIHP_1935__5_2_115_0).

In it I tend to think that $m$ stands for the highest $m\in \mathbb N$ number of draws in a samples $N>m$ from a symmetrical distribution:

*Quand on fait $N $observations ou quand on prend $N$ échantillons
sur une distribution initiale illimitée dans les deux sens, on peut
classer les valeurs numériques qui constituent ces $N$ observations
par ordre de grandeur. Elles seront toutes finies. Il y en aura une
qui sera la plus grande, la dernière valeur, $x_1,$ une autre immédiatement inférieure $x_2,$ que l’on peut considérer comme la plus petite
parmi les deux plus grandes, en général une $m^{\text{ième}}$ qui sera la plus
petite parmi les $\mathbf m$ plus grandes. Considérons ces valeurs en partant
de l’autre extrémité de la suite.*

I don't know if there is a connection to the gamma or the digamma function (psi symbol), but I see that it is approximated one line below in the paper by

$$\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi\, m}}$$

clearly the re-arrangement of the Stirling approximation:

$$m! \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi \,m}\;m^m}{e^m}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable with rate $\lambda$: the limit of binomial random variables in which the the number of trials $n \to \infty$ but the probability of success $p = \frac{\lambda}{n}$ goes to $0$, keeping the expected value at $np = \lambda$. Hence the "law of rare events" in the paper you're reading: this is the law (probability distribution) we get for counting the number of these rare (probability tending to $0$) events in a pool of very many trials.

Then $\Pr[X=k]$ is given by the formula $e^{-\lambda} \cdot \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$. The formula you're looking at is the probability that a Poisson random variable with rate $m$ is equal to $m$. (Here, $m$ is also the expected value of this random variable; I'm not fluent in French, but I bet that this is what *l'espérance mathematique* is.)

You can estimate $\frac{m^m e^{-m}}{m!}$ as $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi m}}$ by Stirling's formula. But this is *also* the estimate provided by the central limit theorem, since for large $m$, we can approximate a Poisson random variable with rate $m$ by a normal random variable with mean $m$ and variance $m$. So actually, this gives us a probabilistic *proof* of Stirling's formula that $m! \sim \frac1{\sqrt {2\pi m}} (\frac me)^m$, starting from the central limit theorem.

Comment: Gee!!! I should at least brought up the Poisson distribution on my OP! Thank you! BTW, I also was tempted to translate it, but I figured I'd better off abstaining.

Comment: Do you have a typo on the very last equation of your post? Square root in the numerator and extended to $\pi$ and $m$?

Comment: I did! Now I have fixed the typo, thanks to you.